Strange behavior of generic types in TypeScript
declare function f(fun: <T>(t: T) => void): void
f((t) => {
    type T = typeof t
    type IsStringArray = T[] extends string[] ? true : false // false

})

function g<T>(t: T) {
    type IsStringArray = T[] extends string[] ? true : false // T[] extends string[] ? true : false
}

IsStringArray is false in the parameter of f, while is T extends string[] ? true : false in the body of g.
What makes the difference?
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIAoVUAueAHgBUA+AjMygSngF5r4A3HLYRsrngChEBOszbwA3oPiz4GAJ4AHBJVbzlIHInky5ilfACSAZwDKGGFlQBzAIIwYUBesoBtALrwQADwwhUYBN4E0trG094AH55GGQEMkQoCBMEAHo0pGTUwUEAX0Zc4kxcfBsqWnp4Jik9WQMEUwsrWwcnFxZqyN9-QODQloivGMt4+ETs9Mz3Lx6AoJCw20iRuISslJB8oA

The (t) => {…} callback doesn't appear to be a generic function (regardless of what fs type says), whereas g is

Wow, this is weird and probably something I'd suggest finding/filing in GitHub to see if it's the intended behavior, a limitation, or a bug. (And I'd probably phrase the example this way to make it obvious that the only difference is with annotated vs contextual type).

@Bergi
I wonder if I can say it's not a generic function because IsString is deferred here
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtVIAoVUAueAHgBUA+AjMygSngF5r4A3HLYRsrngChEBOszbwA3oPiz4GAJ4AHBJVbzlIHInmCZcxSvgBJAM4BBVAvVqQADwwhUwU-ChX4AfnkxkIMohQEKYIAPSh8KCIIDBwwPqyhghmlgrmsVDWLPCUANoAuvD2js6u7goFXj5+AUEh8OHwcBjIMPgYviB6chpGZgDKHVioAOY2RQ5OLvCmQ6NVHX7wtcFhEVExcQm9yaaDMMMj6TCZNpXFU66zB6OV3osIK-WNza34gauCAL6MesSYuHwIyotHoOWY0h6SRMFg82Vsk1Kbg8906TzWkRA0ViIHiUM0MNSx1O8POiOm5Tu1X8SDqGNebWp3QMBIGczG8ImJWm10OC06y1pqwa6yxm1x22hbJuRwyWRyZO5V3ZVIego+z1F2K2XyAA

It is a generic function, but something weird is happening. I’ll probably file an issue when I get to a real computer, which might not be until tomorrow

Now that ms/TS#59450 has been classified as a bug and will likely be fixed, would you like to post an answer here to that effect?

It's a bug and will be fixed soon.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/59450
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/59516
